# How can I convert this left outer join SQL statement in to a LINQ query?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, join, linq-to-sql

this is a bit confusing for me. I know that left outer joins aren't built in to LINQ natively and that you have to use 'into' and 'DefaultIfEmpty()', but I have a bit of a complex SQL query.

The query:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA as a
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB as b
on a.ID = b.ID and a.StatusOne = 1 AND b.StatusOne = 1 AND (a.StatusTwo != 1 OR b.StatusTwo!= 1)
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableC as c
on a.ID = c.ID AND a.StatusOne = 1 AND c.StatusOne = 1 AND (a.StatusTwo != 1 OR c.StatusTwo != 1)
WHERE
a.ID = 99999 AND (b.ID is not null OR c.ID is not null)
```

I'm not even really sure where to begin on this. If someone could help me out I would appreciate it immensely.

Comment: See msdn : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am giving you the idea behind, I didn't tested the code, but to join two tables based on different fields, your join should have a anonymous type to compare.

```
var one = 1

from a in tableA
join b in tableB on new { a.ID, b.StatusOne } equals new { b.ID, one} into ab
```

But in your case you have more than one condition, so before calling DefaultIsEmpty, you should check the latest condition

```
from a in tableA
join b in tableB on new { a.ID, b.StatusOne } equals new { b.ID, one} into ab
from ab in ab.Where(x => x.a.StatusTwo != 1 || x.b.StatusTwo != one).DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Then the other outer join follows the same pattern and you need to make a final join. A good way to start is downloading the LinqPad and see which lambda expression it generates for your query, and you can take it from there. You can optimize it later but you will get the idea behind the generation. Hope this helps

Comment: Ahh thanks so much! You just made it click for me and I was able to get it working. And good call on LinqPad (I admit I completely forgot about it), and it helped me debug tremendously. Much appreciated!

Comment: @Daath if you can post your final code also as part of the answers so people can see it as well. ;)